# Формирование шаблона документа Office

Tags: c#, devexpress

Такая задача - редактировать шаблон документа Word средствами `Devxpress`. В `documentEditor.richEditContro.Options.MailMerge.DataSource` загружаю значения полей подставляемых в шаблон документа. В `documentEditor.richEditContro.CustomizeMergeFields` добавляю метод, который в аргументы загружает список этих полей, от туда при нажатии кнопки insertMergeFieldItem вываливается этот список и мы можем добавить определенное поле в шаблон.

Вопрос - если я хочу иметь две разные кнопки `insertMergeFieldItem` с разными списками как это сделать? При простом добавлении кнопки она автоматом берет поля из аргументов `CustomizeMergeFields` (он общий для всех кнопок).